# Optimize SQL Query containing Like Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, ssms

Trying to make the following query neat and run faster. Any insights are helpful. I have to use like Operator since need to search for the pattern anywhere in the field.

```
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 from TableName where
   (Subject like '%Maths%' OR
    Subject like '%Physics%' OR
    Subject like '%Chemistry%' OR
    Subject like '%English%')
    AND
    (Description like '%Maths%' OR
    Description like '%Physics%' OR
    Description like '%Chemistry%' OR
    DESCRIPTION like '%English%')
    AND
    (Extra like '%Maths%' OR
    Extra like '%Physics%' OR
    Extra like '%Chemistry%' OR
    Extra like '%English%') AND Created Date > 2017-01-01
```

Comment: which sql version?

Comment: most databases support regex. you could use it to simplify your query

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Running Query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 v12

Comment: Using `LIKE` with wildcards like that will never have good performance. It will always do a table-scan. You need to create a [fulltext index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql).

Comment: At best you could try patterns *without* a leading %.

Comment: @TheRecruit the version of SSMS doesn't matter. It's the version of SQL Server that's important.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't optimize this query using basic SQL.  If the strings you are searching for are *words* in the texts, then you can use a full text string.  The place to start in learning about this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search).

If you happen to know that you will be searching for these four strings, you can set up computed columns and then build indexes on the computed columns.  That would be fast.  But you would be limited to exactly those strings.

All is not lost.  Technically, there are other solutions, such as those based on n-grams or by converting to XML/JSON and indexing that.  However, these are either not supported in SQL Server or non-trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `CTE` and `charindex`

compare execution plan from your OP.

```
;with mycte as (   --- building words to look for
 select * from
  (values ('English'),
    ('Math'),
    ('Physics'),
    ('English'),
    ('Chemistry')
  ) t (words)
)
select t.* from
tablename t 
inner join mycte c
 on charindex(c.words,t.subject) > 0    --- check if there is a match
 and charindex(c.words,t.description) > 0  --- check if there is a match
 and charindex(c.words,t.extra) > 0   --- check if there is a match
where
t.createddate > '2017-01-01'
```